# Link between Logarithmic market scoring rule and Automated market makers

Tags: uniswap, markets

In most articles I read about AMMs, there is a link or a mention to Hanson's work about the Logarithmic scoring rule. But I don't clearly see the link between AMM's and the LMSR. Can someone help me ? Like, on Uniswap are used some constant product function, and in some articles (see below) are links to LMSR (Hanson, 2002). Thank you
Here are some articles talking about constant functions market makers : https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.10001.pdf
You can see than there is a reference to Hanson's work in the intro.
here is the article about Hanson's Work:
[http://mason.gmu.edu/~rhanson/mktscore.pdf](http://mason.gmu.edu/%7Erhanson/mktscore.pdf)

Comment: How about sharing that link here (as well as a link to the actual paper which refers to it, in order to see the related context), instead of expecting others to do it for you?

Comment: @goodvibration well, i do not "expect" anyone do search anything, because it is more a general question than a question about an article. Anyway I can share some articles to make it more understandable. See the articles in the main questions.

Comment: The paper discusses some part of the fact that these are incomparable without further assumptions in §3.2 :)